# Problema com carregamento ajax com Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Os carregamentos das minhas páginas são feitos via ajax e carregados dentro da div content. Onde pego a url pelo evento onclick do link, e em seguida, faço o carregamento. As chamadas feitas diretamente pelo menu, funcionam normalmente, mas quando tento pegar o evento onclick dentro da div onde os novos dados foram carregados, o evento não funciona, mas também não da erro.

Os javascripts são carregados no fim da página.

O meu código está assim:

**Layout default.ctp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <title>
        <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>:
        <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
    </title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Capriola' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
        echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
        echo $this->Html->css('lib/unsemantic-grid-responsive');
        echo $this->Html->css('lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom');

        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <?php echo $this->element('menu/menu')?>
    </header>
    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-carregando">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('ic_loading.gif')?>
        <h1>Aguarde! Carregando...</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-mascara"></div>

    <footer>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js") ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js") ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('lib/jquery.scrollTableBody-1.0.0')?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('lib/jquery.maskedinput')?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('core');?>
    </footer>
</body>
```

**Menu: menu.ctp**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
         <li><a class="ajax-link" href=<?php echo Router::url('/unidades/add')"?>Unidades</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**E dentro do arquivo core.js tenho a chamada da página:**

```
$(".ajax-link").bind('click', function(ev){
    _url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(_url);
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Ao entrar na página principal, todo os javascripts e css são carregados normalmente, e a chamada pelo menu funciona normalmente.

Ex: Faço a chamada para a página 'unidades/add' e carrego dentro da div content, mas os links que estão na página 'unidades/add' com a classe 'ajax-link' não funcionam, aliás, qualquer coisa relacionado ao javascript não funcionam. Somente os que foram carregando durante o primeiro carregamento. Porém, quando uso o evento 'onclick' direto no link, aí funciona. Sei que posso fazer assim, mas queria evitar ter que chamar uma função em todos os links manualmente, e usar apenas o evento 'click' do próprio jquery para evitar trabalho em excesso.

Espero que tenha conseguido me expressar de forma correta.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Substitui o "bind" por "on", deve resolver

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está utilizando a versão `1.11.0` do [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) e no seu código eu percebi o seguinte trecho `$(".ajax-link").bind('click', function(ev){` sendo que segundo a [**documentação do método**](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) este `.bind()` foi substituído

> As of jQuery 1.7, the [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the `.bind()` method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements *must exist* at the point the call to `.bind()` occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate()`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Que em tradução livre diz:

> A partir do jQuery 1.7, o método [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) é o método preferido para anexar manipuladores de eventos a um documento. Para versões anteriores, o método `.bind()`é usado para anexar um manipulador de eventos diretamente aos elementos. Manipuladores estão ligados aos elementos atualmente selecionados no objeto jQuery, para que esses elementos devem existir no momento da chamada `.bind()` ocorre. Para a ligação do evento mais flexível, ver a discussão de delegação de eventos em [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) ou [`.delegate()`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Sendo assim você deve substituir `$(".ajax-link").bind('click', function(ev){` para `$(".ajax-link").on('click', function(ev){`.

Se seu elemento não for dinâmico você pode utilizar simplesmente

```
$(".ajax-link").click(function(ev){
    _url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(_url);
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Obrigado! Consegui resolver.